# Angular input's ngModel and Value don't work together

Tags: html, mysql, angular, typescript

I have a problem with the form in angular. My goal is to make a form that is filled with default values ​​that can be changed. After validating the form, it sends the data to the MySQL database.

This is component.html code:

```
<form #adopt="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="success()">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="adoptions.email" #email="ngModel">
        <label for="animal">Twój wybór to:</label>
        <input type="text" name="animal" [(ngModel)]="adoptions.animal" #email="ngModel">
        <button [disabled]="adopt.form.invalid" type="submit">Adoptuj</button>
        <button (click)="getAnimal('')" class="disable">Odznacz swój wybór</button>
      </form>
```

This is typeScript code:

```
export class AdoptpageComponent implements OnInit {

adoptions = new Adoptions();
sessionValue
animal
value
msg='';

constructor(private userService: UserService, private shared: SharedService, private _service 
: AdoptService, private _router : Router) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getUsers();
  this.sessionValue = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
}

getAnimal(arg) {
  this.animal = arg;
}

success() {
  this._service.create(this.adoptions).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("dziala");
      this._router.navigate(['/adopt'])
    },
    error => {
      console.log("nie dziala");
      this.msg = error.error;
    }
  )
}
```

}

The code I posted above works, but only when I enter the value into the form from the keyboard. I want the value from sessionValue to be retrieved automatically in the first form and animal in the second. I managed to achieve it when instead of ngModel I entered:

> <input type="email" name="email" [value]="sessionValue"  #email="ngModel">

But then the form does not work (it does not send data to the database). Unfortunately, when both are used, [value] = "sessionValue" does not work

> <input type="email" name="email" [value]="sessionValue" [(ngModel)]="adoptions.email" #email="ngModel">

do you have an idea what to do to be able to submit the form with the default value?

Comment: if you use [(ngModel)]="variable" you need equal the "variable" to the value you want. In your case you can, in ngOnInit write `this.adoptions.email=sessionStorage.getItem('email')` (1) and of course, not use the "value". (1) be sure that "this.adoption" is not null, else you get an error

Comment: Why you used **#email="ngModel"** in the animal input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: you are binding `adoptions.email` and `adoptions.animal` to `ngModel`, but they are empty(or even worse - `null` or `undefined`) when `ngOnInit` is fired, that is why your inputs are empty. They get value once you introduce text in inputs, that is why you are able to successfully execute `this._service.create`

second: you are causing a value binding conflict. The source of `ngModel` is different from the source of `value`. Once `ngOnInit` is fired `value` tries to load the value of `sessionValue` in input and `ngModel` tries to load nothing, as its source is empty

There is no need to use `value` if you have `ngModel`. You just have to set up start point value for its source variable. like below example

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   adoptions.email = somehowGetEmail()
   adoptions.animal= somehowGetAnimal()
}
```

And that's all you have to do, if you insist on using `ngModels`.

But in general this looks like a lot of unnccessary bindings. Since these are a `form inputs` you should be using `form's preimplemented features for value bindings`. Check docs for angular `FormBuilder, formControl`

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. Thank you for explaining the problem. Thanks to this, I was able to solve it.

Comment: Great to be of help ;)